# Can we say that derivative of a function would be continuous at all points, if we have a function consisting of all differentiable functions?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Can we say that derivative of a function would be continuous at all points, if we have a function consisting of all differentiable functions?

Like in case of $f(x)=x^2\sin\dfrac{1}{x}$, its derivative will be discontinuous as $f(x)$ is containing one non-differentiable function $\sin\dfrac{1}{x}$ which is not differentiable at $x=0$

Comment: What do you mean precisely by "consisting of all differentiable functions"? "Consisting" isn't a well-defined term.

Comment: Also, the derivative of $f(x)$ is continuous everywhere it is defined. Did you mean to also define $f(0)=0$?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this captures what you mean by "consisting of"...

If $f(x) = f_1(x) + f_2(x)$ or $f_1(x) - f_2(x)$ or $f_1(x) f_2(x)$ and $f_1$ and $f_2$ are differentiable at $x_0$, then $f$ is also differentiable there.  If the derivatives of $f_1$ and $f_2$ are continuous at $x_0$, then the derivative of $f$ is also continuous there.

If $f(x) = f_1(x)/f_2(x)$ and $f_1$ and $f_2$ are differentiable at $x_0$
and $f_2(x_0) \ne 0$, then $f$ is also differentiable at $x_0$. If in addition the derivatives of $f_1$ and $f_2$ are continuous at $x_0$, then the derivative of $f$ is also continuous there.

If $f(x) = f_2(f_1(x))$ and $f_1$ is differentiable  at $x_0$ and $f_2$ is differentiable  at $f_1(x_0)$, then $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$.  If the derivatives of $f_1$ and $f_2$ are continuous at $x_0$ and $f_1(x_0)$ respectively, then the derivative of $f$ is continuous at $x_0$.